# Allow inbound traffic on port 80 Ubuntu 18.04 on AWS

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

I've setup an application running locally, then route traffic from port 80 to it using `nginx`.

When I log into the server I can see my application running perfectly at `localhost` on port 80.

On AWS I've added an inbound rule to allow traffic on port 80:

[image]

I've also made sure rules on the UFW firewall allow access to this port:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Yet when I go to an outside machine and run `nmap` on the server I get back:

```
Host is up (0.047s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT   STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp open   ssh
80/tcp closed http
```

Does anyone have any idea why my port 80 would still be closed?